# When adding cookies with selenium, site breaks

Tags: python, selenium, roblox

when messing around with selenium, I found my script was doing something weird. The roblox site works fine until I add a cookie (then all features break), and I assume I was doing something wrong.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver

cookie = "insertcookiehere"

PATH = "/Users/name/Desktop/BadgeBot/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.roblox.com/games/7197745195")
driver.add_cookie({'name': ".ROBLOSECURITY", 'value' : cookie})
driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you are adding the cookies while at the wrong domain. Make sure, the domain you got the cookies from, for example:
'https://www.roblox.com/games/7197745195'

is the same domain you add the cookies to, otherwise - it will break

Comment: Tried switching the domain to "https://roblox.com" but I still get the same problem sadly

Comment: Have you both grabbed cookies and added cookies on the "roblox.com" domain? If so, then there might be a chance that they just don't allow cookie injection

Comment: Is there a way to test this theory (I know it is possible to change cookies if you are already logged in)

Comment: I believe it's just a guessing game, but since Roblox cares about the security flaws this could cause, I'm assuming they disallow that feature

Comment: Thanks for the help, when testing around I found out that if I login in manually, the site continues to work